# Identity 2.0 and generating email confirmation token

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I would like to implement email confirmation , for those users that they would change their email addresses. But i am confused a little bit and lack of documentation ( at least i couldn't find something clear ) . There are 2 methods in UserManager :

1- GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync
2- GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync

What is the difference between those 2 methods and what is their usage  ?

Comment: This will give you general idea of how to change email - see both answers. The longer one is somewhat more safe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570025/net-identity-email-username-change/25585969#25585969

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45270874/809357 to explain differences between the methods